# How to "Retweet" on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I can re-tweet on [Twitter](http://twitter.com). I heard Facebook has similar features. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't quite the same as re-tweeting.  There are 2 related options shown underneath posts:  `Like` and `Share`.

[image]

Like:  This will add a comment to your news feed saying `"<you> likes <title>"`.  It is only a link to the original post - it doesn't add the actual content to your profile/feed.

Share:  It doesn't work for a regular status posting, only if it is a link someone else has posted.  Underneath the post, with `Comment` and `Like` there will be a `Share` link.  This will have it show as a post from you with `"via <name>"` to indicate the original post came from someone else.